# Angular JS app with Closure Compiler

Tags: angularjs, google-closure-compiler

I have an angular app which uses JQuery, bootstrap and few other javascript libraries. I use Uglifier to minify them all together as a single JS (I know it might not be the right thing but works great in my requirement).

I tried to use Closure Compiler to get better compression. It does give me better results but the app is not working when I minify using Closure.

- $ not defined when I use ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
- Cannot find object when the default optimisation was used

NOTE: I have our dependency injection inline with variables to make it work for  Uglifier.

anyone have a clue on what I should do.

I found this [article](http://google.github.io/styleguide/angularjs-google-style.html) on the web but don;t have a clue even whether that is relevant. :(

Can it be because I append all JS (jQuery/bootstrap) together.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With Closure-compiler, ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS is not necessarily better than SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS. Make sure you have read an understand the article [Which Compilation Level is Right For Me?](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html)

You will need externs for all of your external libraries. Angular and jQuery externs may both be found in the Closure-compiler [contrib/externs folder](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/contrib/externs). I'm not aware of externs for Bootstrap.

Even with the externs, you will need to export all of your scope properties from your controllers so that they will be available from templates.

I think you'll find that a applications based on Angular JS will see only a very modest decrease in gzip size after compilation compared to SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.

Comment: Thanks. The correct link is [Which Compilation Level is Right For Me?](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html)